# getContentResolver().delete() throws IllegalArgumentException sporadically

Tags: android, android-contentprovider, android-contentresolver

We released a beta of our product, it works for most users, but one user with OnePlus 5T/Android 8.1 reports a sporadic exception:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resume activity {com.ourproduct/com.ourproduct.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unknown URL content://com.ourproduct.data/delete
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3726)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3766)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1737)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6753)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:482)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
Caused by:java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unknown URL content://com.ourproduct.data/delete
    at android.content.ContentResolver.delete(ContentResolver.java:1745)
    <... here is our code stacktrace ...>
```

I contacted the user and got some additional info: the issue does not happen every time he uses the operation, just sometimes.

The content provider is defined in the same application.

The code is trivial, just for completeness of the question:

```
protected void unsetValue(final String group, final String name) {
    myContext.getContentResolver().delete(
        uri("delete"), null, new String[] { group, name }
    );
}

private Uri uri(String location) {
    return Uri.parse("content://com.ourproduct.data/" + location);
}
```

Any ideas? Maybe I can ask the user for some additional info?

Comment: Looks like that exception is thrown when the `ContentResolver` can't get a `ContentProvider` for the given URI. My best guess is that this happens when the user doesn't have an internet connection.

Comment: An internet connection? For a "content://" URI?

Comment: Oh, yeah, ok. I was thinking you were doing an http DELETE call

Comment: are you really trying to delete a resource called `delete` - `content://com.ourproduct.data/delete` ? or have you masked the real uri resource name?

Comment: "ourproduct" is a placeholder. The real code contains the real name.

Comment: Curious to hear if you got a resolution in the end... We are seeing the same issue in our app, a few random `IllegalArgumentException` errors in an otherwise ok app.